# Selecting biggest number smaller than a variable in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array and a variable like so;

```
var a = [0, 1200, 3260, 9430, 13220],
    b = 4500;
```

What would be the smartest way to select the largest value in the array that's still smaller than or equal to the variable?

In this example, I'd need to select `3260`.

I could do something like this;

```
$.each(a, function(i){
    if(a[i] <= b && a[i+1] > b){
        var c = a[i];
        return false;
    }
});
```

But I'm thinking that might not work if the selected array value is the last one. Not to mention, to me it looks like a lot of code for something rather simple.

Is there a smarter/less verbose way of achieving what I'm after?

*(and yes, I know I shouldn't have used a jQuery loop for that but I'm lazy when typing examples)*

Comment: If that `a` array is always ordered, you can perform [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on that array. But if the array is small size, then you can traverse it linearly... it would be negligible time profit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another way you could to it is through a combination of array filtering and apply(), which I think is a very readable approach.
The call to filter() just returns an array of elements in a which don't satisfy the predicate function and then apply() calls Math.max with each element as an argument.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = 4;
var result = Math.max.apply(Math, a.filter(function(x){return x <= b}));
```

Result will be equal to 4.

Comment: Gotta love one-liner solutions, and this one seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
  if (a[i] <= b && a[i] > max) { 
    max = a[i]; 
  } 
}
```

I think the above approach is quite simple, readable, and not very verbose. An alternative would be to use `reduce`, like so:

```
var max = a.reduce(function (i, j) { return j <= b ? Math.max(i, j) : i }, Number.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the a array always sorted? In this case, you could optimize your code along those lines (you might want to check the indexes, I haven't checked the code):

```
var beginning = 0;
var end = a.length;
while ((end-beginning)>1) {
    var currentIndex = Math.floor((beginning+end)/2);;
    if (a[currentIndex] < b) {
        beginning = currentIndex;
    } else if (a[currentIndex] > b){
        end = currentIndex;
    } else {
        beginning=end=currentIndex;
    }
}
var max = a[beginning];
```

Comment: @Stano The edit was too minor. a comment is enough. The P should take the steps to improve the answer and the OP to read comments

Comment: I have added the changes you suggested, Stano. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

grep() of jQuery

```
 var a = [0, 1200, 3260, 9430, 13220],
 b = 4500; 
 var c= Math.max.apply( Math,$.grep(a,function(n){return n<=b}));
 document.write(c)
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aWkcV/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var closest = null;
$.each(a, function() {
    if ( closest == null || Math.abs(this - b) < Math.abs(closest - b) ) {
        closest = this;
    }
});
```

A jQuery variant if that for some reason would be desired.

Answer (score 1):

Following should do:

```
function getHigh(arr, max){
  var c;
  for(var i = 0, len=arr.length; i<len; i++){
    if(a[i] <= b) c=a[i];
    else return c;
  }
  return false;
}
```